# how to import rendered <jsp:include ... > in js

Tags: jquery, jsp, jspinclude

I have a js like below:

```
    var html=""
    $.getJson("getRelatedDynamicFields.json", { ajax: 'true'}, function (data) {
       switch(data[0].ReferenceType) {
          case "Table1":
               html += '<jsp:include page="Page1.html">';
               break;
          case "input":
                html += '<input id="' + data[0].id + '" type="text"/>';
                break; 
.
.
.
       }
    }
    $('#myDiv').html(html);
```

the second case works find, but the first case doesn't. I get the page with error and not loaded completely.
how should I do this?

Comment: Provide more informations: how does Page1.html looks like, what's the error etc.

Comment: do you have any java stuff in your Page1.html? we cannot help until you post necessary code and error occured.

Comment: As jsp is for server side, it will be not possible to use jsp tags `(<jsp:include)` in javascript/jquery and append it in client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding html content as

jsp tag is a server side code so it won't get executed at client side.

One way to achive the same you you get the whole html of Page1.html through ajax call and place inside the div if data[0].ReferenceType is Table1. This will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I imported the page through ajax and it worked just like jsp:include. thanks :)